# Adding data attributes in HTML when using Spring form tags

Tags: java, html, spring, jakarta-ee

How do you add a data atttribute to a Spring form tag?

The IDE is complaining: **Attribute data-attribute invalid for tag textarea according to TLD**
This is the namespace I am using: xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"

Comment: *"The IDE is complaining"*  IDEs do not complain, they simply report.

Comment: `data-*` attributes are supported since Spring 3.0.

Comment: But there must be a workaround/solution?